# Could not load library after latest ROS updates

Tags: ros, catkin, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all the community.
I'm writing this since I'm encountering errors when I launch my custom controllers written for a KUKA LWR arm, used in combination with Gazebo simulator. The error comes when I run the roslaunch command which loads such controllers.

```
**[ERROR] [1421148091.366974261, 5.814000000]: Could not load class kuka_controllers/BacksteppingController: Failed to load library /home/enrico/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libkuka_controllers.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/enrico/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libkuka_controllers.so: undefined symbol: _ZN26forward_command_controller24ForwardCommandControllerIN18hardware_interface20EffortJointInterfaceEE8startingERKN3ros4TimeE)
[ERROR] [1421148091.367239553, 5.814000000]: Could not load controller 'BacksteppingController' because controller type 'kuka_controllers/BacksteppingController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1421148091.367296142, 5.814000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types**
```

The weird thing is that running the command suggested by ROS (rosservice call [...]) it actually returns all my controllers names. This error has been introduced after the last ROS software updates and before that it was working just fine. Also I have a call to PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS in my source, so it is not that the problem.

As a note, the ROS built-in position controllers work, so it seems like a linking or a parsing error (also notice that in the library path there is a double / after 'lib', which may the responsible). I've already tried to rebuild the workspace, still the same error.

Thanks in advance,
Enrico C.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200885/could-not-load-library-after-latest-ros-updates/) by [Enrico C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/21366/enrico-c./) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This symbol `_ZN26forward_command_controller24ForwardCommandControllerIN18hardware_interface20EffortJointInterfaceEE8startingERKN3ros4TimeE` does not exist in the library you are loading but it is expecting it to. Run through `c++filt` on a Linux machine:

```
forward_command_controller::ForwardCommandController<hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface>::starting(ros::Time const&)
```

This means that you library was likely built against one version of headers but linked against a version of the library without this symbol. Either way, this sounds like an ABI breakage, you can try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to make sure all of the packages involved are at their latest version. You can also rebuild you from source packages, taking care to make sure the libraries get rebuilt.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-14**:
On @Enrico C.'s behalf: Hi William,
also to me it seems like a linking problem. Unfortunately the `dist-upgrade` didn't find any software to update. I think I'm going to try manual building or wait for the next update. To be safe, I've also reverted to an old github commit of my code, where it was

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-14**:
On @Enrico C.'s behalf: surely working fine, and the problem didn't go away. Thanks for your answer, by the way.

Enrico

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-14**:
No problem. If I were you I would try to track down where that missing symbol is coming from and then look at the source for that and see if it has changed recently.

**Comment by [logan.dunbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/40877/logan.dunbar/) on 2019-04-21**:
Bless you good sir for teaching me about that lovely command. Bless you.